# Acceleration of sequential computation over time

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, microprocessor, scaling

I am looking for a model (or "law", as in Moore's law) to describe the acceleration of sequential computation over time. By sequential computation I mean, for example, repeated applications of a hash function (e.g. SHA256). (Another example would be repeated multiplication modulo an unfactorisable RSA modulus.)

In his keynote David Patterson has a chart about "single program speed" (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZNR_0Hfxo4&feature=youtu.be&t=993)) which more or less captures what I am looking for. Does this metric have other names, and have there been studies about it?

Below is an image from "Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach":

[image]

Comment: This question isn't appropriate for a site devoted to electronics design. I've recommended that it be migrated.

Comment: Where do you suggest it be migrated to?

Comment: Re: migration. Am I to surmise that a question about Moore’s law, which is specifically about microprocessor engineering, would not belong to this Electrical Engineering site either?